# Magento - custom module that captures user e-mail as soon as it is entered

Tags: magento

In a custom extension, I'm thinking I might like to capture the user's e-mail address as they enter it in the various places that it can be entered (Checkout, Create Account, Log In). I might not, *but* if I did...

I think the best way to do this would be to inject a piece of JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to do that. I guess I need to specify a block in a layout file? So maybe,

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="before_body_ends">
        <block type="mymodule/myblock" name="not sure" as="not sure" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

and in the block class, the _toHtml() method could return some JavaScript that added an event handler [onchange] to the email address field, and the implementation of the event handler made an AJAX call to a controller passing the e-mail address entered.

I think the above layout class would result in JavaScript being injected in every page. I would only want it on the ones that contain an email address entry field. What layout file should I create to do that (location, name, and contents).

I went through the demo site and viewed the source of the pages where an e-mail address is entered. The id of the email address field is different in each case, so the JavaScript would have to account for that.

Many Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to include a .js file on every page you should add it to page.xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
           <action method="addJs"><script>relative/path/from/js/folder</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Wait for the dom to load and setup your javascript observers.

Comment: Or as a layout update in a module... either way, this should do the trick. If this needs server-side stuff too, it should be in that module. In any case, the XML is the same.

Comment: @Janus Tondering. Thank you for your replies. I didn't want to add a js file to every page, just a js snippet to some pages, but your post on layouts pointed me in the right direction. As you suggested, I have created a layout file in my own module that references the sections of the layout from the modules I am interested in. It is working well. Well, apart from the fact I am having difficulty invoking my controller action from the JS as I'd like to specify /myfrontname/mycontroller in the post, but I need to inject an index.php on the front to get it to work, and that's not generic.

Comment: If you have url rewrites working it should not be necessary to have index.php in the url.